# Wireshark mis-interprets my UDP (port 5000) message as TAPA protocol

Tags: wireshark

I'm writing a UDP send program which will send data to 127.0.0.1, port 5000.

When I use Wireshark to sniff my data packet, it interprets the protocol as TAPA protocol, which is unexpected. What I was expecting is that Wireshark treats the data packet as a general UDP data packet and display the payload data, not to parse it as a TAPA datagram.

Expected Wireshark result:
[image]

Unexpected Wireshark result:
[image]

Comment: it's confirmed that if I just change the data itself (port number unchanged), Wireshark will change the protocol type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark, like many dumping tools, will attempt to interpret the data it receives using a number of fingerprinting strategies.

If your data looks sufficiently like that protocol, or shares a port that's commonly used for that sort of traffic, it may be inadvertently tagged as such.

Port 5000 is quite a non-random number to use. Why not something else?

Comment: this is actually what I want to confirm: does Wireshark choose protocol only by port number or by package data pattern as well?

Comment: Try on a different port and see if it guesses the same. There could be something in your data that's tripping a match as well, perhaps by coincidence.